# Django AbstractUser not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, models, django-users

I am trying to inherit from AbstractUSer my models.py looks like:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):        
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

MyUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

now by declaring email as unique field and username as a required field my superuser is being created successfully and also is being authenticated properly but I am having a problem while creating any other user as if I am creating any user through my admin page its not being authenticated.It always returns

> None

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from credilet.models import *

admin.site.register(MyUser)
```

What I am thinking is that the create_user is not being called properly as if I see in my admin page the password is not hashed so that means the create_user is not being called properly.Somebody please help through it or even if you have a proper documentation on abstractuser

> not abstractbaseuser

so please refer that to me in the solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the authentication system you have to use AbstractBaseUser,
[look at this full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

AbstractUser is ok to [Extend Django’s default User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user).

Comment: i just want to use email as my username but by extending it through abstract base user I have to go through all the backend system I mean I have to define my custom create_user and create_superuser and all that stuff and for avoiding that I used Abstract user so is there any possibility that I could use abstract user and and just define my username and rest of the things just same as django's user object

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `UserAdmin` into admin.py for Myuser 
if you does not add `UserAdmin` , password can't be hashed with django:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from credilet.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin) # add UserAdmin
```